# rails, rspec, shoulda validate_presence_of failed with setter called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2, shoulda

In a simple rails app with a company model

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Attributes
  attr_accessible :name

  validates_presence_of :name

  def name=(s)
    self[:name] = s.upcase
  end
end
```

When the following spec file is run. it fails.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Company do

  before :each do
    @company = Company.new({name: 'my_company'})
  end

  it "should validate presence of name" do
    @company.should validate_presence_of(:name)
  end

end
```

Debugging showed that the name=(s) method is called twice, once with 'my_company' and once with nil.

I don't get why a second call happen with nill.
 here are the gems used:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'mysql2' 

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0' 
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', :require => false
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Shoulda is meant to be used to write one liner specs as mentioned in the documentation like
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name)}
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name).with_message(/is not optional/) }

  So you can write your spec in more readable fashion as follows:

  ```
  describe 'validations' do  
   it {should validate_presence_of(:name)}  
   end
  ```
- Regarding your question of two assignments for the name field  :

  1. First assignment is done in your spec's before(:each) block and
  2. **Shoulda presence validator tries to assign nil value for all attributes you specified to be validated for presence**, which in case of your model is **:name**.
     Your overridden name= method takes place for this nil value, and it raises an error as it can not upcase nil. One liner spec shown above will also fail for the same reason. To solve this problem you can change you setter method to do **s.try(:upcase)**. So it can work on nil values and won't cause any problem.

Comment: regarding your 2. where do you get this information?"Shoulda presence validator tries to assign nil value for all attributes". I still don't get why the method is called twice. the first call name as a value, second call it is null.

Comment: @alpha, I went through the code of shoulda **validate_presence_of_matcher**.There is a method **matches?**, which internally call **disallows_value_of(blank_value, @expected_message)**. If you follow this code you will see the assignment to nil value getting done in **matches?** method of AllowValueMatcher

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be you mentioned `name` in the new `name` method.

Better to use `write_attribute` method as the doc you referred.

To read it as:

```
 def name=(s)
   write_attribute(:name, s.upcase)
 end
```

Comment: the second method name= modify the value of name, so I need it. what should be the proper way? and it doesn't explain why the second call has a nill value parameter

Comment: @Alpha, yes I know you need it, but you don't need to write that def, because `attr_accessible :name` has already generated  this method for you automatically.  Remove that def and you code will work.

Comment: aren't you confusing attr_accessible and attr_accessor? if you remove attr_accessible you get "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name"  also http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Overwriting+default+accessors seems to show it the way I did it

Comment: @Alpha, yes,  my fault. But you did not follow the same way, you mentioned `name` in your new `name` method, I guest that's the reason of error. See the doc, they use `write_attribute`, that should be correct way.

Comment: look at the botom of the documentation "You can alternatively use self[:attribute]=(value) and self[:attribute] instead of write_attribute(:attribute, value) and read_attribute(:attribute)." I guess self[:name]=s.upcase is valid